# Include header directory automatically Automake

Tags: cmake, automake, libtool

I have an Automake project which has the following directory structure:

```
Makefile.am
src/
src/common
src/common/common.c
src/common/common.h
src/common/Makefile.am
src/mylib
src/mylib/mylib.c
src/mylib/mylib.h
src/mylib/Makefile.am
```

On `src/common/Makefile.am` there is a  Libtool convenience library target:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libcommon.la
libcommon_la_SOURCES = common.c common.h
```

On `src/mylib/Makefile.am` there is a Libtool public shared library target:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmylib.la
libmylib_la_SOURCES = mylib.c mylib.h
libmylib_la_LIBADD = ../common/libcommon.la
```

Now I expected Automake to be smart enough to automatically add to  `libmylib_la_CFLAGS` the `-I` pointing to the directory where `common.h` is, since it depends on `libcommon.la`.

Is there actually a mechanism to either enable this (similar to CMake's `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`) or maybe a variable (e.g. `libcommon_la_HEADERS`) that already contains all headers belonging from `libcommon` convenience library ?

I have researched everywhere and could not find a way to it instead of adding `-I ../common/` directly to mylib CFLAGS.

Comment: You can think of Automake is an extension of make, which only does what you tell it to do. For example, should `-I../common/` be added to `libmylib_la_CXXFLAGS` as well as `libmylib_la_CFLAGS` if you happened to list a C++ source file as well? What about `CPPFLAGS` and `CXXCPPFLAGS`?  Automake doesn't do what you don't tell it to do. Also, `src/mylib/Makefile` may not know how to create `../common/libcommon.la` that is a dependency because its build rules are in a different Makefile, so hopefully you control the build to always build `libcommon.la` before `libmylib.la` (assuming you can).

Comment: Also, `libXXX_la_CFLAGS`, `libXXX_la_CPPFLAGS`, etc. are the closest Automake analogues to CMake's `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property. There also exists `AM_CFLAGS` and such that allow you to add the listed include directives to _every_ compilation line rather than adding them to every single target, similar to CMake's `include_directories` command.

Comment: In fact I originally structured the Makefiles as non-recursive included in the main `./Makefile.am`, so the dependency issue would be indeed sorted (omitted here for the sake of simplicity). I don't see `AM_CFLAGS`'s much utility for a non-recursive automake system, since you can't control the scope of it. it's either adding the flags to all compilations or adding individually one by one. `libXXX_la_CFLAGS` is indeed an option but then you will get all other undesirable non `-I` flags.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I expected Automake to be smart enough to automatically add to
>   libmylib_la_CFLAGS the -I pointing to the directory where common.h is,
>   since it depends on libcommon.la.

As you discovered, Automake does not do this automatically.

> Is there actually a mechanism to either enable this (similar to
>   CMake's INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) or maybe a variable (e.g.
>   libcommon_la_HEADERS) that already contains all headers belonging from
>   libcommon convenience library ?

Just writing out the variable is the only mechanism.  If you have to do it many times, you can use an include file or use an `AC_SUBST` in your `configure.ac`.

Note that in Automake, it's usual to put `-I` options into one of the `_CPPFLAGS` variables.  And, depending on what your library does -- in particular if it generates any header files -- you may want to also have it refer to both the source and build trees.  So the result might look like:

```
libmylib_la_CPPFLAGS = -I$(srcdir)/../common -I../common
```